# What does "honor" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, nouns, word-in-context

What does "honor" mean in this sentence?

"Mather wanted the service to be available to everyone, so he tried a pay-what-you-can honor system—but everyone claimed to be poor."

Source: A More Beautiful Question: The Power of Inquiry to Spark Breakthrough Ideas (Book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "[honor system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_system)" (or honesty system, or trust system) for payments is a system which doesn't try to force people to pay, but depends on trust that they will pay, and assumes that the customers are honest.

A simple example would be a person selling apples by putting a box of apples on a table and a pot for collecting money and a sign that says "apples: 10p each", then leaving the table.  The person trusts that customers will pay for the apples and not steal, but the person doesn't try to check or force people to pay.

In this example the system was more like "{the service}:  pay as much as you want, rich people should pay more".  The system trusted that people would be honest.  It didn't work because people weren't honest, and everybody claimed to be poor.

Comment: I think that 'honor system' may be mainly a US usage (the spelling of 'honor' is, perhaps a clue), so maybe that should be 'apples 10c each'? We do have 'honesty systems' in the UK.

Comment: Does "pay-what-you-can" have a different meaning from "honor system"? I feel like "honor system" is more about the honesty of the customer and a predetermined amount of money ("You should pay this amount of money to us, but we're not going to do anything if you don't"), while "pay-what-you-can" is more about voluntary paying ("You can pay, but it's fine if you don't").

Comment: And yes, "honor system" is an American usage because I sourced it from a book by an American journalist.

Comment: It is a type of honor system. A price isn't enforced, instead it depends on the seller trusting the buyer to truly pay what they can.